# can I remove imagemagick by deleting directories?

Tags: macos, imagemagick, homebrew, rails, gem

I posted this to StackOverflow, but probably belongs here.

I'm on OSX Lion, trying to get back to basics so I can run RMagick in Rails 3.0, using rvm.

When I tried to add the RMagick gem to Rails using bundle, I got compile errors. It also responded that there were multiple copies of ImageMagick. Checking with macports, I found 3 versions, and used ports to remove them.

After trying again, I don't see the error related to multiple copies of ImageMagick, but I get the error

```
checking for stdint.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
```

I've just re-installed XCode, and have installed some things since that required gcc that went fine, so I don't think there's a problem there.

```
brew list --unbrewed | grep Image
```

shows a lot of files related to ImageMagick the include subdirectory, lib subdirectory and the share subdirectory. They seem to relate to ImageMagick 6.6.4. Can I simply delete these files to get rid of ImageMagick? Will this help?

Comment: Your question should only be posted once at a time. Either leave it here *or* on Stack Overflow please.

Comment: I'm actually not 100% sure which site this belongs on, so I'll just leave a link to the SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578463/can-i-remove-imagemagick-by-deleting-directories

Comment: yes – it's right down the middle programming and sys admin. I understand that its preferrable not to cross-post, but each community has a possible perspective...

Comment: alright – can't answer my own question here, but I deleted the config file at /usr/local/bin/Magick-config and that at least allowed the RMagick gem to install without complaint. Will find out if it works with Carrierwave or Paperclip next...